# Forbidden when I try to POST to Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, post, azure-functions, http-status-code-403

I have daployed an Azure function.

The function application is secured by Azure Active Directory, so in order to call it I have to log in using my AAD credentials.

And everything is fine when I make a GET call to that function.

But when I try to make a POST call, I'm receiving following error:
`403 Forbidden` `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

The function is deployed using Visual Studio and its entry point looks like this:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(
        AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, 
        "post", "get", 
        Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req, 
    TraceWriter log)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working fine for me and below are the steps what I did:

1. Deployed azure function v1 from Visual studio with the below code:

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // parse query parameter
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            if (name == null)
            {
                // Get request body
                dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                name = data?.name;
            }

            return name == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
        }
```

2. Enable EasyAUth from Portal using AAD.

[image: EasyAuthImage]

3. Get the ClientID and Client Secret of your AAD application from the Authentication / Authorization Blade.

[image: ClientID/ClientSceret]

4. Get the Token using below Postman call:

[image: Postman]

5. Once you get the token from the postman as shown above, make a call to azure function using the same token shown below:

[image: FunctionCall]